# How to keep the value of a string?

Tags: c++, vector

Hey guys I have a question about variables and If statements.

The reason I am asking is I am assigning tokens in a vector of strings to variables but if my vector only has 3 elements and I try to assign a variable to myVector(5) I get an error.

This is my solution to that problem

```
std::string element5;
if(myVector.size () >= 4)
(
    std::string element5 = myVector.at(4)
}
```

But that wont change the string outside the if statement? My code works fine if I have exactly 5 elements and no error check but if I'm passing in standard input I wont really know how many elements there are all I will know is that there are a max of 50 elements.

I dont need to ouput any elements just run this code on each one

```
if(countSubstring(element5,"a") > 0)
{
    a = a + 1
}
```

then I would output a.

how do I make element5 keep its new string?

Comment: Can you give us the actual code you need to run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Problem

Your code here redefines your variable `element5`:

```
std::string element5;
if(myVector.size () >= 4)
(
    std::string element5 = myVector.at(4)
}
```

Here you first declare `element5` after the first line, and then you re-declare it at the third line in your `if` statement. That essentially "recreates" the variable `element5` for that scope `{}`. And then of course is `pop`ed right after the scope. So you won't see a change in `element5` if you try to print it out of the scope.

### Solution

Easy, just don't re-declare your variable, and you're all set! Like so:

```
std::string element5;
if(myVector.size () >= 4)
(
    element5 = myVector.at(4)
}
```

### Why is this happening?

Like I said, down in the assembly level the variable gets `push`ed, and then suddenly when it comes down to another level and the same variable gets re-declared, the global variable gets forgotten about. And as soon as the scope ends:

```
{
  //This is a scope
}
```

the re-declared variable gets `pop`ed off the stack, and we have our original `element5` back! This will leave `element5` in the same position since you didn't actually change it ;).

### Undefined Behaviors(UB)

Don't reference to an out-of-scope object; don't do it!

[C++: Reference to "out of scope" object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9941502/5768335)

### References

[What happens when C++ reference leaves it's scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3097593/5768335)

[What happens in C++ when I pass an object by reference and it goes out of scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7603833/5768335)

### Glossary

**scope**: The "container" a program is currently executing under; for example, let's take this:

```
int main() {
  //1st scope
  if (true) {
    //2nd scope
    {
      //third scope
    }
  }
}
```

**Undefined Behavior(UB)**: 
When in an  **undefined**/**unknown** state at any time given during the compilation. Compiler does whatever it decides to do, making it a very dangerous Behavior especially if you are writing a big project! Here is a good question/answer to this topic:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99692/philosophy-behind-undefined-behavior

Comment: @ddog your welcome! Any questions no problems for answer. By the way this is my final version of edit.. sorry for the multiple editing :P

Comment: Great answer, but the definition of UB is wrong. It means what will happen is not documented by the C++ standard. Undefined/unknown state will almost certainly trigger UB or be the result of UB, but UB is what happens, not what is.

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining the string inside the if statement, you shouldn't do that because you want to use the string that has been declared before.

So just replace `std::string element5 = myVector.at(4)` with `element5 = myVector.at(4)`